# Shiny Dashboard actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny Dashboard with a reactive action button but the button does not update the dashboard.

I have the tabItems split out into their own files and references using source by ui.R.

The tabItem within contain just the following code.

```
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
```

The server.R file is also split out and references each file using source.
The the relavent file contains

```
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      runif(input$n)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(randomVals())
    })
```

Clicking the actionbutton does not do anything within ShinyDahsboard, but if I run this code as a shiny app on it's own it works fine.

Comment: I have added a submit button and if I click the action button and then the submit button the plot updates. Unlike without shiny dashboard the go button just updates the plot.

Answer (score 3):

You should `isolate` your button, like so:

**Edit: as per @tospig**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(basicPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    numericInput("n", "n", 50),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )),
  server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      runif(input$n)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(randomVals())
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: From [using action buttons](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) - "Like `observeEvent()`, `eventReactive()` isolates the block of code in its second argument with `isolate()`" - this implies you don't need `isolate()`, doesn't it?

Comment: @tospig you're right, dont need to do it. I edited my answer